# Package private visibility related change in java 8?

Tags: java

In an Android app I changed the java compiler to java 8 then the following piece of code stopped working:

```
final Map<String, String> allRecords = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>() {
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Entry eldest) {
        return size() > 10;
    }
};
```

It says: Entry is not public in LinkedHashMap; cannot be accessed from outside package

However it compiles originally. I am not aware of any package private visibility related change in java 8. Is there any reference to this behavior change in java 8?

Comment: I can't imagine the rawtype is doing you any favours whatsoever.

Comment: Try using `Map.Entry` instead of `Entry` in `removeEldestEntry`

Comment: Changing to Map.Entry works but original code compiles with java 7. Why this gets changed in java 8? Entry itself is package private I think the syntax Map.Entry makes more sense. But do you know if there is any reference or document about this change?

Comment: @darklord see my comment in regards to that in my answer. It shouldn't be different between the two versions, but apparently is. Gonna look into it and I'll let you know.

Comment: @darklord from what I can tell, it appears to be a hierarchy issue; Entry is not declared in LinkedHashMap (whereas it is in Map) in both java 7 and 8, so it's probably something related to that.

Answer (score 3):

You're referencing `LinkedHashMap.Entry`, which is private in `LinkedHashMap`, according to that errror. Using `Map.Entry` instead will resolve this issue, although I'm unsure why changing Java platforms would affect this as the access should be the same in all versions.

By looking into the API documentation, Entry is not declared in LinkedHashMap, whereas it is in Map, so this may simply be a change to the hierarchy loading in java 8, Although this may be incorrect.

See Documents...
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html, 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

You must take the map from the Entry

```
final Map<String, String> allRecords = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>() {
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
        return size() > 10;
    }
};
```

this  line   `Map.Entry`

Changing the package and folder caused this